# How to use just-audio?

Tags: flutter, dart, just-audio

I have an mp3 file with multiple MP3s inside, like:
[file1][https://i.stack.imgur.com/qejF9.jpg]

With every mp3 file’s index and contentLength known, how can I play it?

how can I play it? thanks

Refer to android MediaPlayer

```
setDataSource(FileDescriptor fd, long offset, long length)
```

Comment: Hi, I see you are new here and welcome to SO! I had integrated just_audio a while back and this article https://suragch.medium.com/background-audio-in-flutter-with-audio-service-and-just-audio-3cce17b4a7d clearly explains many things we need to do. While I can't understand the question very well, I thought to share it with you for learning.

Comment: have multiple audio files written into a file in a specific format. And I would like to play the audio files by Offset and ContentLength.How could I achieve it?
In Android, specific ways to achieve it are as follows.

Comment: refer to android MediaPlayer
`public void setDataSource(FileDescriptor fd, long offset, long length)`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly add below package in pubspec.yaml file

> audioplayers: ^0.19.1

and follow this small demo:

```
AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();

Future play() async {
  int result = await audioPlayer.play('url');
  if (result == 1) {
    // success
  }
}

Future pause() async {
  int result = await audioPlayer.pause();
  if (result == 1) {
    // success
  }
}

Future stop() async {
  int result = await audioPlayer.stop();
  if (result == 1) {
    // success
  }
}
```

You can also use mp3 from files by this package.
If it found useful just give upvote.

Comment: I only have one mp3 file， contains a lot of small mp3 files

Comment: So you mean 1 mp3 folder which contains various mp3 files?